# Netezza Loading table from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, netezza

I have a very large table stored in SQL Server and I now want to transfer this table to the Netezza system. Do I need to use SSIS in order to accomplish this task?

Before this, I've only had to use Aginity to load tables that were stored on the network and not in a server to Netezza, so loading from another server is new to me. Can someone guide me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would unload to a file in UNIcode format and load to Netezza with an external table. Just remember to change all string datatypes to nvarchar unless you are 100% English in your data (not likely these days)

I know it sounds 1980 but it’s (still) the most performant and reliable method